# How to write an npm package that uses crypto in browser but falls back to node:crypto on server

Tags: node.js, webpack, cryptography, webpack-5

I maintain a package called [`react-querybuilder`](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder) that generates unique identifiers using `crypto.getRandomValues()`.

When used in the browser, this is not a problem as `crypto` is [available pretty much everywhere now](https://caniuse.com/getrandomvalues). But `react-querybuilder` can be used on the server for query processing (including generating IDs) as well as server-side rendering, which means the `crypto` package must either be polyfilled with `crypto-browserify` or loaded manually (something like `globalThis.crypto = require('node:crypto')`).

Some build setups require the polyfill even if they don't do SSR, e.g. [Create React App v5](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756) since it uses Webpack v5 (which doesn't automatically include polyfills like v4 did). CRA v4 doesn't have the issue.

**How can I write the package to use `window.crypto` when running in the browser, but load `node:crypto` and use that instead when running on the server?** Ideally the setup would avoid requiring anything extra of the end user (polyfills, config, etc.).

This is the [current implementation](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/blob/1db5c8562b629c3732325b062c7e2608d1f56e65/packages/react-querybuilder/src/utils/generateID.ts) at time of writing (comments removed):

```
let cryptoModule = globalThis.crypto;

if (!cryptoModule && typeof require === "function") {
  cryptoModule = require("crypto").webcrypto;
}

const template = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
const position19vals = ["8", "9", "a", "b"];
const re = /[xy]/g;
const container = new Uint32Array(32);

export const generateID = () => {
  cryptoModule.getRandomValues(container);
  let i = -1;
  return template.replaceAll(re, (char) => {
    i++;
    return char === "y"
      ? position19vals[container[i] % 4]
      : (container[i] % 16).toString(16);
  });
};
```

FWIW, I'm not opposed to having separate builds for client and server if that makes it easier to implement (for me *and* the end user, but mostly the end user).